# How to create object from a class and invoke method in the MVC framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Kindly help me learn asp.net MVC concepts using the simple Model class below. Where do I create a Student object and how do I pass the value using the constructor and finally invoke a StudentMessage() method and show the results in the View (index.cshtml). I have been trying to create a Student object in the Student Controller class but it's not working. Please don't use List collection. I am a beginner in C#.

```
namespace MyMVCApplication.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public Student(int studentID, string studentName, int age)
        {
            this.StudentId = studentID;
            this.StudentName = studentName;
            this.Age = age;
        }

        public string StudentMessage()
        {
            string message = "Student ID: " + this.StudentId + "| Student Name: " + this.StudentId + "| Age: " + this.Age;
            return message;
        }
    }  
}

namespace MyMVCApplication.Controllers
{
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Student
        public ActionResult Index()
        {            
            return View();
        }      
    }
}
```

View - Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
```

Comment: `I have been trying to create a Student object in the Student Controller class but it's not working`. What does "*it's not working*" mean? that is a broad statement.

Comment: And when you say 'I have been trying' - what specifically (code) have you tried?

Comment: I've tested your code and "create a Student object in the Student Controller class" does not return any error. `Student student = new Student(1, "Peter", 34);` works ike a champ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass your Student model to your view, do this:

Pasting your model to your view

```js
public ActionResult Index()
{            
    Student modelStudent = new Student(studentID, studentName, age);

    return View(modelStudent);
}
```

Right now you need to receive your model in your view **INDEX**, the add the following code to your index.cshtml:

```js
@model MyMVCApplication.Models.Student
```

Now you can acess the model properties in your view using commands like this (No need to invoke a method...):

```html
Student ID: @Model.StudentId | Student Name: @Model.StudentId | Age: @Model.Age
```